# Mongoid query on hash fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a rails app with mongoid5.
In my `Project` model has an attribute like this:

```
permissions : {
 "18748343" : 2,
 "23453744" : 3,
 "23453444" : 1
}
```

and an array like this

```
role_ids = ["123456", "23453744"]
```

I want to query on projects that has one of the `role_ids` members as key in their `permissions` attribute and value of that key is more than 1.
How can I make this query with mongoid criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic, mongoid5 will allow you to query like this:

```
Project.where('permissions.123456'.ne => nil)
```

This is because in mongo, permissions is document, with keys

Comment: Is that supposed to be a symbol or does Mongoid5 add all the operator methods to `String` as well as `Symbol`?